# Is Ajax considered client or server-side scripting?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Is Ajax considered as client or server side scripting?

Comment: How on earth is it "not possible to know what is being asked here"? It's a silly question, yes, but it's absolutely not "not a real question".

Comment: Since this question has been pointlessly closed (seems to be happening at greater rates these days) I'll answer here.  AJAX is its' own concept.  It's a much needed bridge between client & server that was "never" there before (it was there, but it sucked until goog made it asynchronous. Imagine having tons of ajax requests but you have to wait for the first one, currently hung up, to finish before getting the rest finished).  People will say client side, but the server also has to be able to give you data back.  Client & server have always depended upon each other.  Now, they can talk.

Answer (score 9):

The technology which co-ordinates the AJAX approach (i.e. javascript) is client-side, although server-side scripts/servlets are needed to give the response.

Answer (score 4):

Client. It runs on the browser only, and make requests to a server, just like the requests browsers do for any web page

Comment: "Just like" is overstating a bit.  Most browsers wouldn't know how to post a form as JSON, for example.

Comment: @cHao: The format of the submission is on a higher layer than what we're talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Client side scripting.

However, Microsoft has also released server controls which ajaxify their ASP.NET pages, like the updatepanel control. Those are server side. Note that this is a specific implementation.

Comment: Wow, after 1.5 years suddenly a -1. I can understand that nowadays the UpdatePanel control is considered a nono but in the past it was one of those most favored controls on the market.

Answer (score 1):

[Ajax is client side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), but it will (almost always) access a server that is providing the data.

Sometimes the server scripts will have no specific support for Ajax as they are just returning XML style data, but in other cases the server may have specific support written in - for example in the popular case of [JSONP](http://www.json-p.org/).

[EDITED ANSWER]

Comment: It does not need server side support. However, a server can offer APIs tailored for Ajax requests.

Comment: It needs to access a server if you want to do anything useful with it. That's what I meant by server side support.

Comment: @Roger: Ah ok. Well, I think that should be something obvious. For every communication over the internet one needs to be connected to it and have access to the servers.

Comment: @Felix: Sure it does. If there's nothing on the server-side, then it won't work! What it doesn't need is specific support that's not already provided for non-AJAX HTTP requests.

Comment: @Tomalak: Ok, it depends at which level we are discussing this. I was under the assumption that, as Ajax is mostly used on websites, access to web sites is a premies and yes, I actually meant that it does not need *specific* support. Of course if there is no server I can connect to, there is no point of making an Ajax request or even using the browser to open a web site.

Comment: Wow, didn't mean to spark such a debate, I think we all know what Ajax is and isn't. I've edited my answer to make it clearer what I meant when I foolishly used the words 'server support' :)

Comment: @Felix: Yes, clearly I know what you intended to say. But "it does not need server side support" is clearly patently false, so...